# Reference request: proof of Stokes theorem using chains and boundaries

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I am pretty inexperienced in differential geometry and wanted to go through the proof of Stokes theorem.  The usual way I see it formulated is for an oriented manifold with boundary $M$.   There was a particular way I saw it presented before, and was wondering if there was any reference which did things in this way.

I know what I am going to say is just a translation of the usual formulation of Stokes theorem, so if there is no such reference, I will just read a more standard treatment and translate the proof into a way I like.

So $M$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth  manifold, and $\Omega^k(M)$ is the space of differential $k$-forms on $M$.  We have a cochain complex

$$\cdots \rightarrow \Omega^0(M) \rightarrow \Omega^1(M) \rightarrow \Omega^2(M) \rightarrow \cdots $$

where $d: \Omega^i(M) \rightarrow \Omega^{i+1}(M)$ is the exterior derivative.  For each $k$, we also consider all smooth functions $[0,1]^k \rightarrow M$ (meaning smooth on the interior $(0,1)^k$, with some nice boundary conditions), and let $C_k$ be the free vector space with all those smooth functions as a basis.  There are natural (?) boundary maps $\partial: C_i \rightarrow C_{i-1}$ which give us a chain complex

$$\cdots \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow \cdots$$

If $f: [0,1]^k \rightarrow M$ is a basis element of $C_k$, and $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$, then the pullback $f^{\ast} \omega$ is a differential $k$-form on the manifold $(0,1)^k$, and one defines a pairing $C_k \times \Omega^k(M) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$$\langle f, \omega \rangle = \int\limits_f \omega = \int\limits_{(0,1)^k} f^{\ast} \omega$$

where the right hand side is the usual integration of a top form in $\mathbb R^k$.  One extends $\langle f, \omega \rangle$ by linearity to all $f \in C_k$.

The version of Stokes theorem I heard is the following:

> **Theorem**: Let $\omega \in \Omega^{k-1}$, and $f \in C_k$.  Then
>
> $$\langle f, d \omega \rangle = \langle \partial f, \omega \rangle$$
>
> or in other words
>
> $$\int\limits_f d \omega = \int\limits_{\partial f} \omega$$

Is there a nice reference which explains Stokes theorem in roughly the way I'm describing?  If not, how is what I am saying related to the usual formulation?  For one thing, I don't understand why Stokes theorem is stated for an oriented manifold.  The formulation I have described says nothing about an orientation on $M$.

Comment: In H. Heuser Analysis II there is a proof involving chains. But this is a very special case. There is a reason, why manifolds are usually in the statement.

Comment: There is no simplification in the proof gained by working with simplices as opposed to general manifolds with corners. The proof is always to use partitions of unity to reduce to Stokes' theorem for compactly supported $n$-forms in $[0,\infty)^k \times \Bbb R^{n-k}$. Now, simplices are canonically oriented, which is where the orientation is secretly hiding here. But it is true that $\Omega^*(M)$ pairs against $C_*(M)$ for any manifold $M$, not necessarily oriented.